# "Incremented" CSS class in element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Let us suppose that we have a div element `#a-node` and a javascript method create one or more other div's called `.b-node` (not need inside this first) and it too add an `#a-node` class `.b-node-enabled`.

Exists a way to toggle/turn on the `.b-node-enabled` only if exists `.b-node`'s connected specifically to `#a-node`?

Example:

- If no one `.b-node` is connected with `#a-node`, so turn class off;
- If one or more `.b-node` is connected with `#a-node`, so turn class on;

I can use jQuery, if need and `-webkit` features.

**REAL PROBLEM**

I have a div popup that create a background, and I need turn on a classe on the main content body (that not inside this popup, and vice-versa, just appended to body too), and I can have more than one popup enabled at same time. I only need turn off the `.b-node-enabled` if no one popup is showing.

```
<body>
    <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
    <div id="a-node" class="b-node-enabled">...</div>
    <!-- POPUPS -->
    <div class="b-node">...</div>
    <div class="b-node">...</div>
    <div class="b-node">...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your question could use some clarification. If I get it, you need `#a-node` to get the class `.b-node-enabled` if there is any popup, is that correct? Do you have access to display and hide pop-up events? And third, how can you tell whether a pop-up is being displayed?

Comment: 1. Exactly; 2. I create the popup, so I have full control. 3. I create it with a *class* that I write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I really understood your question, but maybe this code snippet can help you (jQuery needed).

```
function updateANodeClass() {
    if ($(".b-node").length) {
        $("#a-node").addClass("b-node-enabled");
    } else {
        $("#a-node").removeClass("b-node-enabled");
    }
}
```

After you've added or removed one `.b-node` you'll have to call that function to update the class.